# Paint is scraping and wiping off too easily

Tags: painting, paint, repainting

I recently painted some of my house with Glidden Duo eggshell (primer included).  Days after painting, my wife informed me that the paint was wiping off and scraping off extremely easy (just the new paint- you can see the old paint underneath). This is still happening after about a month. I've never seen this happen before.  The paint underneath was a Valspar latex eggshell and was put on about 7 years ago.  I wiped down the walls before painting.  Any ideas why this might be happening and what I can do next time to prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

[It looks like other people have had similar problems with this paint.](http://www.glidden.com/products/duo-paint-and-primer-eggshell.do) It could be a bad batch of paint, or a strange interaction between the old paint and the new, but I think it's more likely that the wall just needed a little more preparation than is normal.

Most modern latex paints will stick to glossy undercoats pretty well, but it never hurts to rough up the underlying surface with a 100-150 grit sand paper. I've also heard several painters say that the best prep they ever did was wiping everything down with a 1:10 solution of Clorox Bleach and water. Anytime I paint anything, I will run over the whole surface with a scraper just to get anything that comes up easily.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Could be be bad paint, could be bad prep. Is the paint coming off everywhere or just some places? In and around the kitchen walls develop a small coating of grease if you don't have a good range hood that you use every time you cook. Even when you do. Good to clean walls before painting other rooms too.

Elaborate on what you mean by "wiped down the walls". Did you just run a damp rag over them? Did you use any cleaning solvents? Some cleaning solvents like TSP also need to be rinsed off. Others like the TSP substitutes don't need to be rinsed.

Painted walls have a bit of texture from the roller stipple so you need to scrub a bit to get down into it.

Paint over one mediocre paint with another without proper prep and there's a greater chance that things can go wrong. I hate painting so I always buy the best paint that I can (usually one of Benjamin Moore's better lines) and spend a lot of time on prepping the walls so I don't have to paint again.

Try calling Glidden to see what they have to say. Chances are that they'll try and blame it on the prep (rightfully or not) but you might get some good info.

Comment: Just wiping with a damp sponge.

Answer (score 1):

I would remove a section of the new paint with a scraper, then sand it with 150 grit sandpaper, then reapply the paint. After it dries I'd see if it adhered well. If not, I would blame the paint and contact Glidden. Otherwise, I'd remove all the paint, sand, and repaint.

Answer (score 0):

Surface prep is everything with paint.  Cleaned and lightly sanded is usually adequate.

Is the paint just chipping or coming off in small bits or is it coming loose in huge sheets?  Is the problem in multiple rooms or just one?  These are things you will want to know before you call Glidden.

I suspect it's more of a case of improper surface prep.

Things you can do before re-painting, scrape what you can off the wall or sand it off.  Then prime as a totally separate coat, no paint and primer in one(consider an oil base primer, but that may not be necessary).  Give the primer a few days to cure, scuff sand, then paint.